# Why can't the logarithm be extended to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ using the identity theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I know that for complex numbers $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$ the following is not always true:
$$
\text{Ln}(z\cdot w) = \text{Ln}(z)  + \text{Ln}(w) \tag{1}
$$
where Ln is the principal branch of the complex logarithm. It is however true for $z, w \in \mathbb{R}$ and I fail to see how the Identity Theorem can not be applied for the domain $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$. We can set $w = w_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and obtain two functions from the left and right hand-side of the equation:
$$
f = \text{Ln}(z\cdot w_0) \\
g = \text{Ln}(z) + \text{Ln}(w_0)
$$
f and g are both holomorphic on $\Omega$ since Ln is holomorphic on $\Omega$. They are also identical on a set that has a clusterpoint, namely $\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$. By the identity Theorem $f(z) = g(z), \forall z \in \Omega$. Repeating this process with a fixed $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and variable $w \in \mathbb{C}$ will yield Eq. $(1)$ for $z, w \in \Omega$ which I know to be false. Where did I make a mistake and the line of reasoning breaks down? I know that this argument can be used to show $\sin(z + w) = \sin(z) \cos(w) + \cos(z) \sin(w) \ \ \forall z, w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies in the assumption that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. For instance, if $w_0=i$ and $z=i$ too, then $f(z.w_0)$ is undefined.

Comment: $w_0$ is chosen to be a real number and $f$ is only a function of $z \in \Omega$ so this specific counterexample is not valid. But I see now that this would still cause a problem for a positive real $z$ and negative $w_0$ though. That would explain why this argument is valid for $w, z \in \mathbb{C}$ where $w, z$ both have positive real parts. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @FractalSalamander Yes, I missed the assumption that $w_0\in\Bbb R$.